# Jenkins BUILD now issue

Tags: jenkins

In the jenkins applications ,I accidentally clicked on the " Build Now " instead of "Build with Parameters"  link while trying to Build the application and now its stuck . I am unable to cancel this Build. I tried building the application again however I am unable to promote my new build because the previous Build is still not complete. Is there any way I can abort the previous build ?

Answer (score 0):

in Jenkins Script console (/jenkins/script) try:

```
Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(jobName,Job.class).getBuildByNumber(jobNumber).doStop()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you are logged in and you have permissions for aborting the build (should be at job's configuration page)
2. Jenkins could need some time to process the abortion request.
3. If you notice that Jenkins is definitely stacked, check the reason. 
   It could be memory, CPU or space issue.
   These Linux commands are highly recommended:

   > top
   >
   > df -h
4. The last and the most unpleasant way is rebooting Jenkins and starting the new job. NEVER try that on production machine :)